# Characterizing the Homotopy of Path-Connected Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

I am currently really stuck and confused about the following problem from Topology II of Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences (Springer, Novikov/Fuchs):

Give an example of two path-connected spaces that are weak homotopy equivalent but not homotopy equivalent.

The problem is that I am not sure if there are such examples at all considering the Serre fibration lacking for path-connected spaces or their basis.  Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Hint: can you come up with an example of a weakly-contractible space (i.e. all homotopy groups vanish) which is not contractible? By Whitehead's Theorem such an example *cannot* be a CW complex, so think of the weird/pathological spaces you know.

Comment: @William unfortunately I could not find any.  What are those?